# How to generate entities and update database schema in Silex

Tags: doctrine-orm, silex

I use doctrine ORM

I create entity without console. It looks like

```
Trololo\Event:
  type: entity
  table: events
  readOnly: false
  id:
    id:
      type: guid
      generator:
      strategy: UUID
 fields:
    dateCreated:
       type: datetime
       nullable: false
    name:
       type: string
       length: 75
    startDate:
       type: datetime
       nullable: false
```

How can I tell doctrine, for this filed? I need create database, now I need
create table.

Comment: Do you want to generate the entity (as written in your title) or create the database schema from this file?

Comment: @A.L generate and then update database schema

Comment: What does "*How can I tell doctrine, for this filed?*" mean?

Comment: I mean witch command i must use

Answer (score 2):

By default, Silex support only the `DBAL`package of Doctrine for database. If you want to use the `ORM`package and have it integrated in your application, you would have to use a `ServiceProvider`

[List of a few services providers for Silex](https://github.com/silexphp/Silex/wiki/Third-Party-ServiceProviders)

To use the command line for building your database/schema, you will have to use doctrine command lines from the library itself (it's not wrapped in `console` as it is in Symfony)

[Here is the list of Doctrine's commands](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/tools.html)

Comment: It looks like it's simpler to use Symfony2 instead of Silex to deal with entities.

Comment: Not really, it's just they way you call it that change, to create your DB schema with symfony you do : php app/console doctrine:schema:create and with doctrine you do: php vendor/bin/doctrine orm:schema-tool:create (if you have installed doctrine with composer). You will have to configure the doctrine console tool to find your entities. That has more to do with going with Silex over Symfony that the doctrine part